# Dealing with trivial cases in the consequent in proofs

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I'm proving a statement of the following form:

> $P(C) \rightarrow \Big((C=\emptyset) \vee (C=\mathbb R) \vee Q(C) \Big)$

Where $P(C)$ means the set $C$ has the property $P$ and $Q(C)$ means the set $C$ has the property $Q$. It might also be worth noting hat all the statements on the RHS are exclusive, i.e. each one implies the other cannot be true.

It's slightly embarassing, but I've realized I am not entirely sure how to prove that statement. My proof would intuitively be something like

> Assume $C\neq \emptyset$ and $C\neq \mathbb R$, then $P \Rightarrow Q$

that is
$$\Big(P(C) \wedge \neg (C=\emptyset) \wedge \neg (C= \mathbb R) \Big) \rightarrow Q(C)$$

From the statement of $P$ it is immediately obvious that if $C$ were the empty set or the real line, $P$ would be true, but that seems like the opposite implication to me, i.e. $(C=\emptyset) \rightarrow P(C)$

How do these statements relate to the original statement? How do I used them to prove it?

Thank you.

**edit**: I've edited my question quite heavily to hopefully make it more obvious what the issue is. I think I'd like to really see how this plays out in a more formal logic language, because I often catch myself doing everything intuitively and, ultimatelly, I feel that this is a dangerous road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proposition $\varphi\to(\psi\lor\chi)$ is logically equivalent to the proposition $(\varphi\land\neg\psi)\to\chi$; this is easily checked with a truth table, for instance. Note that $\psi$ can itself be a disjunction. In your case, for a specific $C$

- $\varphi$ is $P(C)$,
- $\psi$ is $C=\varnothing\lor C=\Bbb R$, and
- $\chi$ is $Q(C)$.

Thus $\neg\psi$ is $C\ne\varnothing\land C\ne\Bbb R$, and your second highlighted block is essentially $(\varphi\land\neg\psi)\to\chi$, which is logically equivalent to the original proposition.

In short, whenever you want to prove that some condition implies that at least one of a list of possibilities is true, you can assume the condition and the failure of all but one of the possibilities and (try to) prove that the remaining possibility must obtain; doing so is logically equivalent to proving the original implication.

Comment: You answer sounds reassuring (certainly helps me with not feeling stupid), but sadly doesn't help me much with understanding of the issue. I will edit my question to make it more answerable, but before I do that: could you explain, possibly formalize your last sentence? I am not sure what it means, exactly.

Comment: @DahnJahn: If you’ve carred out the argument in the highlighted box, you’ve proved that every $C$ that has property $P$ and is neither empty nor $\Bbb R$ also has property $Q$. That *almost* shows that *every* $C$ with $P$ has $Q$; the only possible omissions are $\varnothing$ and $\Bbb R$. If you really want to prove that every $C$ with $P$ has $Q$, you have to cover those possible omissions: if either $\varnothing$ or $\Bbb R$ has $P$, you have to prove separately that it also has $Q$, because it’s not covered by the original (highlighted) argument.

Comment: I am not sure that I want to prove that every $C$ with $P$ has $Q$, if that is indeed true, this might be (one of) the source(s) of my confusion. See my edited question. I suppose - since the intuitive explanation doesn't seem to make me understand - an asnwer including more formal logic might help. Thank you for trying so far, though :)

Comment: @DahnJahn: I’ve completely rewritten my answer in the light of your edit; see if it helps.

Comment: Yes, this definitely helps! I will think about this properly (i.e. do the truth table and convince myself why it works) later, as I have to leave now, but this definitely answers my question. Thank you.

Comment: @DahnJahn: You’re welcome.